# Problems with pop-ups in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have some trouble with pop-ups right now. I want to have some pop-ups with images in it, but every pop-up only displays the image of the last pop-up in the list (in this case the 20th). I searched for it and it says that there is an error in the `newWindow.document.write(text);`, but it might as wel have something to do with the `setTimeout( function()`. I hope you guys can help me out.

This is the code:

```js
<HEAD>
<title>PopUp</title>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function popups(){popupWin1();popupWin2();popupWin3();popupWin4();popupWin5();popupWin6();popupWin7();popupWin8();popupWin9();popupWin10();popupWin11();popupWin12();popupWin13();popupWin14();popupWin15();popupWin16();popupWin17();popupWin18();popupWin19();popupWin20();}
function popupWin1() {

text =  "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:6px; HEIGHT:100% src=giphy4.gif style=height:100%></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin1','width=800,height=400,left=100,top=100,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 1000);  
// time delay of pop-ups
}

function popupWin2() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=tumblr_o4j9rpai7K1tj7oyqo1_500.gif style=height:100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin2','width=900,height=800,left=700,top=600,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 5000)

}

function popupWin3() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=randycano_pre.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin3','width=400,height=600,left=30,top=400,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 10500)

}

function popupWin4() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=giphy.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin4','width=1000,height=800,left=500,top=100,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 15500)

}

function popupWin5() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=tumblr_o2w65pSscx1uluhv2o1_500.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin5','width=800,height=500,left=600,top=400,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 17500)

}

function popupWin6() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=BelovedVacantChihuahua-size_restricted.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin6','width=700,height=450,left=200,top=700,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 20000)

}

function popupWin7() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=giphy2.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin7','width=450,height=750,left=400,top=400,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 22000)

}

function popupWin8() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=rcano1.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin8','width=900,height=400,left=550,top=500,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 27000)

}

function popupWin9() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=jelly-gummies-db-test-01.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin9','width=850,height=670,left=450,top=600,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 33500)

}

function popupWin10() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=giphy3.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin10','width=550,height=600,left=150,top=100,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 36000)

}

function popupWin11() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=9897574_one-year-of-gifs--gif-six-pack_t4d3d6bfc.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin11','width=400,height=900,left=750,top=700,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 39500)

}

function popupWin12() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=giphy4.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin12','width=500,height=900,left=350,top=100,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 42000)

}

function popupWin13() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=200.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin13','width=500,height=650,left=850,top=700,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 45500)

}

function popupWin14() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=giphy5.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin14','width=500,height=650,left=50,top=250,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 47600)

}

function popupWin15() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=201.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin15','width=500,height=750,left=50,top=200,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 48700)

}

function popupWin16() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=202.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin16','width=500,height=500,left=150,top=0,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 49800)

}

function popupWin17() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=giphy2.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin17','width=500,height=700,left=350,top=100,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 50850)

}

function popupWin18() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=black><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=202.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin18','width=500,height=600,left=0,top=800,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 51900)

}

function popupWin19() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=yellow><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=giphy4.gif style=height:100% width=100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin19','width=500,height=620,left=30,top=0,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 52950)

}

function popupWin20() {

text = "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<body bgcolor=yellow><img STYLE=position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; src=randy-cano-melting-motion-graphics-animation-designboom-818_2.gif style=height:100%;></body>\n</html>\n";
setTimeout( function()
{
newWindow = window.open('','newWin20','width=500,height=400,left=650,top=400,');
newWindow.document.write(text);
}, 54000)

}

</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY onLoad="popups()">
```

Comment: The main problem with this, is that it won't work in any modern browser as they block this kind of annoying stuff. On the other hand, it looks like the code was written in 1998, so maybe it's time to pull the deLorean out of the garage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so your problem was that when you create the HTML to be displayed in the popup, you name it "text". And then you call that text every time, essentially calling the first HTML over and over.

```
newWindow.document.write(text);
```

You have the above line 20 times.
Change it to:

```
-- CODE --
newWindow.document.write(text1);
-- CODE --
newWindow.document.write(text2);
-- CODE --
newWindow.document.write(text3);
-- CODE --
```

I stylized your code a bit, and it is working fine. Take a look:

```
function popups(){popupWin1();popupWin2()}
    function popupWin1() {

        text =  "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<title></title>" +
                "<body bgcolor=black>" +
                "<img STYLE=position:absolute; " +
                "TOP:0px; LEFT:6px; HEIGHT:100% " +
                "src='http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a' " +
                "style=height:100%>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";
        setTimeout( function()
        {
            newWindow = window.open('','newWin1','width=800,height=400,left=100,top=100,');
            newWindow.document.write(text);
        }, 1000);
    }
    function popupWin2() {

        text2 =  "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<title></title>" +
                "<body bgcolor=black>" +
                "<img STYLE=position:absolute; " +
                "TOP:0px; LEFT:6px; HEIGHT:100% " +
                "src='https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png' " +
                "style=height:100%>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";
        setTimeout( function()
        {
            newWindow = window.open('','newWin2','width=800,height=400,left=100,top=100,');
            newWindow.document.write(text2);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. :)

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. :)